# How to use activation checkpointing with a language model?

Tags: hpc, pytorch-lightning, huggingface

I am using HuggingFace's Flan T5-base model (~220 million parameters) in pytorch lightning with `deepspeed`. I am getting out-of-memory errors (batch size = 1, with 32 steps of gradient accumulation). I want to use activation checkpointing to help with the issue. The [documentation](https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/advanced/model_parallel.html#deepspeed-activation-checkpointing) provides the following as an example:

```
from lightning.pytorch import Trainer 
import deepspeed
class MyModel(LightningModule):    
    def __init__(self):         
        super().__init__()         
        self.block_1 = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(32, 32), nn.ReLU())         
        self.block_2 = torch.nn.Linear(32, 2)
    
    def forward(self, x):         
        # Use the DeepSpeed checkpointing function instead of calling the module directly         
        # checkpointing self.block_1 means the activations are deleted after use,         
        # and re-calculated during the backward passes         
        x = deepspeed.checkpointing.checkpoint(self.block_1, x)         
        return self.block_2(x)
```

This does not make it clear to me how to use activation checkpointing when using a language model. For example, my (oversimplified) code would look like this without checkpointing:

```
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM
class MyModel(LightningModule):     ...
    def __init__(self):         
        super().__init__()         
        self.lm = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained('google/flan-t5-base')
    def forward(self, x):         
        return self.lm(**x)
```

How would I modify this to use deepspeed's checkpointing? The documentation specifically says don't wrap the entire model as `return deepspeed.checkpointing.checkpoint(self.lm, x.input_ids)`. So—is there a canonical way of using this checkpointing with a language model?